# How to insert a tree into another tree in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree

I have two trees like these:
[image]

I want to insert the second tree into the first tree in a node that has the same name of its root and attach the children of this node to the left most child of the second tree.

I tried:

```
    PTree attachPoint = chain.Find(x => x.Val == RTree.Val);


    if (attachPoint != null)
    {
        foreach (var c in attachPoint.Childs)
        {
            RTree.Left.Childs.Add(c);
        }
        attachPoint = RTree;
    }
    else
    {
        RTree.Left.Childs.Add(root);
        root = RTree;
    }
```

Here, `RTree` is the second tree and `root` points to the root of first tree and `chain` holds the branch from root "A" to "D". But it seems the desired tree is not built. Did i do it correctly?

Comment: What's the maximum number of children of a node? That doesn't look like a binary tree but a node contains a `Left`-child-node. Looks weird.

Comment: @Verarind you can suppose `RTree`, the second child, is binary, and `Left` is actually childs[1] and `Right` is `childs[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been easier to help if you have included the essential parts of your `PTree` class. Here is what I could suggest you based on the posted code:

```
PTree attachPoint = chain.Find(x => x.Val == RTree.Val);

if (attachPoint != null)
{
    foreach (var c in attachPoint.Childs)
    {
        RTree.Left.Childs.Add(c);
    }
    // Here you either have to find the attachPoint parent and
    // replace attachPoint with RTree in parent.Childs,
    // or make attachPoint.Childs to be RTree.Childs as below
    attachPoint.Childs.Clear();
    foreach (var c in RTree.Childs)
    {
        attachPoint.Childs.Add(c);
    }
}
else
{
    RTree.Left.Childs.Add(root);
    root = RTree;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`attachPoint` (and `root`?) are just local variables so `attachPoint = RTree;` will not affect the structure of the tree. You need to search the left tree to find the parent node of the insert point and then modify the parent node so that `parent.Right = attachPoint;`